# How to reuse the same javascript code in a single blog?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript question and answer section on my blog. When the user selects an option, if the option is correct, it turns green , else the selected answer turns red and the answer is revealed by making it green. Finally the explanation division is shown

```html
 <h2>Questions</h2>
    
    <div id="Q&A" style="background:white;">
    
    <p>1. If we increase the frequency of oscillation, the velocity of the wave... </p>
    
    
    <div id="W1box" style="background:white; font-size:20px;padding:10px;border: 2px solid black;" >
    <input id="W1input" name="option" type=radio value="wrong" onclick="showwrong1()"> 
    Increases </input>
    </div>
    
    <div id="W2box" style="background:white; font-size:20px;padding:10px;border: 2px solid black;" >
    <input id="W2input" name="option" type=radio value="wrong" onclick="showwrong2()"> 
    Decreases </input>
    </div>
    
    <div id="C1box" style="background:white; font-size:20px;padding:10px;border: 2px solid black;" >
    <input id="C1input" name="option" type=radio value="optionA" onclick="showcorrect()"> 
    Does not change </input>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <div  id="correctexp" style="background:white; display:none; "  >
    Correct!<br>
      $v=f\lambda$ does not mean that velocity is directly proportional to frequency.<br>
    When we increase frequency($f$), waves are closer-hence the wavelength($\lambda$)  decreases keeping the velocity unchanged ($v=f\lambda$).<br>
      Velocity only depends upon the material property of the medium of propagation.<br>
      For example sound waves in water moves faster than in air because water has higher density.
      <br>But the speed of sound waves does not change if we speak in higher frequency.
    </div>
    
    <div  id="wrongexp" style="background:white; display:none; "  >
    
      $v=f\lambda$ does not mean that velocity is directly proportional to frequency.<br>
    When we increase frequency($f$), waves are closer-hence the wavelength($\lambda$)  decreases keeping the velocity unchanged ($v=f\lambda$).<br>
      Velocity only depends upon the material property of the medium of propagation.<br>
      For example sound waves in water moves faster than in air because water has higher density.
      <br>But the speed of sound waves does not change if we speak in higher frequency.
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    </div>
        
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
    
    function showcorrect()
      {
        
      var correct = document.getElementById("C1input");
      var x = document.getElementById("correctexp");  
       if(correct.checked==true)
          document.getElementById("C1box").style.backgroundColor="PaleGreen";
       if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";}
      }
          
     
            
    function showwrong1()
      {
      var wrong = document.getElementById("W1input");
      var x = document.getElementById("wrongexp");   
        if(wrong.checked==true)
        document.getElementById("W1box").style.backgroundColor="#FAA0A0";
        document.getElementById("C1box").style.backgroundColor="PaleGreen";
       
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";}
      
        
      }    
      
    function showwrong2()
      {
      var wrong = document.getElementById("W2input");
        if(wrong.checked==true)
        document.getElementById("W2box").style.backgroundColor="#FAA0A0";
        document.getElementById("C1box").style.backgroundColor="PaleGreen";
        
        var x = document.getElementById("wrongexp");  
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";}
      
      
      }      
      
      
      
    </script>
```

But i want to add another question below this. But when i copy and paste this code, it gives errors like when I click the option in the second question, the box in the first question turns red and so on.

I know that I can change the id and name of the functions, But is there a more efficient way to do this because I might have to include many questions like this?

Comment: Can you show me in jsfiddle?

Comment: Only way I see it is to dynamically generate the whole page.

Comment: you have to write the function for reusability

Comment: @iamdlm like put each question in a division and show it only when clicked? I don't know much about javascript.

Comment: Will this be used for real? Because anyone can inspect the page and know which answer is the correct one by searching for `onclick="showcorrect()"`. Ideally the correct answer should be checked server side.

Comment: @iamdlm This is not a serious quiz. Just for the user to evaluate how much they have learned. The results are not saved and this is not an like an exam or anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write reusable function something like:

```js
function showwrong(v1, v2, v3)
      {
      var wrong = document.getElementById(v1);
      var x = document.getElementById("wrongexp");   
        if(wrong.checked==true)
        document.getElementById(v2).style.backgroundColor="#FAA0A0";
        document.getElementById(v3).style.backgroundColor="PaleGreen";
       
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";}
      
        
      }
```

and then you can simply call it with appropriate arguments, like:

```js
showwrong("W1input", "W1box", "C1box")
```

Comment: That isn't working. What am I doing wrong? fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/fcgkdtLv/

Comment: Your syntax for radio button itself is wrong, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/f4eav931/1/